# Broadcast Message from root@

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm running Lion (10.7.1) and the other day I started getting these Broadcast Message notices in my Terminal.  I've google'd the crap out of it and the few threads i've found where someone actually offered a way to fix it haven't solved my problem.  I'm at a loss as to how to fix this and I use the Terminal daily and it is very annoying.

```
Broadcast Message from root@Gregg-Bolingers-iMac.local                         
        (no tty) at 18:31 CST...                                               

Feb 21 18:31:14 Gregg-Bolingers-iMac kernel[0]:
```

Looking at my system.log the only thing I get when this happens is:

```
Feb 21 18:31:55: --- last message repeated 22898 times ---
Feb 21 18:31:54 Gregg-Bolingers-iMac kernel[0]:
```

Comment: And now it has stopped.  No idea what has changed.  Frustrating.

Comment: And now it is happening again.

Comment: `sudo chmod 0 /usr/bin/wall` :-)

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: See @emb's description. But don't do it - that'd be like smashing your TV because you don't agree with something it shows to you. Better to find and fix the actual cause :)

Answer (score 1):

The command Ingmar Hupp provided removes all access to your 'wall' program. This 'write all' program will send a message to all users logged into the system at one point.

I am assuming no one else has access to your machine, so perhaps there is a program you use that makes an errant (or perhaps malicious) call to /usr/bin/wall?

By changing the permissions of /usr/bin/wall to 0, no internal or external source should be able to read, write or execute the program.

Hope this explanation helps!

One more thought: Have you updated your OS to the most recent version? I have come across other instances of this where users traced the issue back to a security update released by Apple.